# Date filtering in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have Access reading from a global database, and there is a column where dates are presented in YYYYMMDD format, and I am looking for SQL code that lets me filter it between yesterday and the first day of the current month (it will not be running on the first day of the month, so I'm not worried about it breaking there).

For example, I currently have it working using the code: Between 20170201 And 20170221

I'd like to have it use a code that is Between [FIRST OF MONTH] and [YESTERDAY]

Comment: What do you mean by "Sort it between two dates". Do you mean filter? Is this a date stored as text, or just a funky date format in a date field?

Comment: Filter, I believe.  I am to get it to show transactions that happened between the first of the month and the previous business day.  If I write " Between 20170201 And 20170221" it will work just fine, but I need it to automatically update day by day.

Comment: "Between 20170201 And 20170221" implies that your data is stored as int, is this correct? In this case, the solution would be to convert the dates (the first of the current month and yesterday) to this format.

Comment: I would imagine that is correct.  The data itself is stored remotely, so I'm using a pass through in Access to get to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where YourDateField 
    Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1) And DateAdd("d", -1, Date())
```

If the date field really is text, use:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where DateValue(Format(YourDateField, "@@@@\/@@\/@@"))
    Between DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1) And DateAdd("d", -1, Date())
```

or:

```
Select * From YourTable
Where YourDateField 
    Between Format(DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1), "yyyymmdd") And Format(DateAdd("d", -1, Date()), "yyyymmdd")
```

If you use a PT query, convert to the syntax of the SQL engine.

Comment: Thanks! That helps a lot.